# How to get the max of the row of distinct username

Tags: mysql

My sql table is below

```
id,username,logfile
1,admin,20200521-072805.txt
2,admin,20200521-072845.txt
3,admin1,20200521-072857.txt
4,admin1,20200521-074933.txt
5,admin2,20200521-075857.txt
6,admin2,20200521-076852.txt
```

Expected out

```
2,admin,20200521-072845.txt
4,admin1,20200521-074933.txt
6,admin2,20200521-076852.txt
```

I want to fetched latest data from the mysql table

My query is giving latest of all data

```
SELECT distinct(username),log_file FROM table WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM table);
```

Comment: I think you simply group by the username and order by id desc it's work.
SELECT username,logfile from table group by username order by id desc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a correlated sub query

```
 select username,logfile
    from table t
    where id = (select max(id) from table t1 where t1.username = t.username)
```